# how to using "stopPropagation" on parent dom?

Tags: javascript, stoppropagation

[image]

In pic above，parent dom node has its event and child nodes have too.

I can use stopPropagation in Child to prevent bubbling.

but in that case, if have too many children, too much stopPropagation should writed. Is there a function using on parent node can stop child bubble ?

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible of course, if I understood you question. Not sure what the problems is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to avoid doing the work the parent's event handler does if the event passed through a particular kind of child element. In that case, in your parent event handler, you can use `event.target` to figure out whether the event passed through a matching child.

In semi-pseudo-code:

```
theParentElement.addEventListener("the-event", function(e) {
    for (var node = e.target; node && node != this; node = node.parentNode) {
        if (isChildWeWantToFilterOut(node)) {
            return;
        }
    }

    // parent handler logic that you only want to run when the
    // event didn't pass through a relevant child
}, false);
```

Comment: brilliant！！！that's exactly what I need. sorry for my poor English causing the confusion.